# How can I generate a random number between 0-5 in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, random

I have only been coding in my off time for a couple of weeks now and am creating an app with a very basic "guess how many" concept. The user will enter a number between 0-5 and the app will tell the user whether they are right or wrong.

How would I generate a number between 0-5?

Answer (score -1):

You can use any random method and performing modulo operator on it

```
let randomNumber = random() % 6
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! May I ask what the "%" does? It is simply stating that if 6 = n then it's n -1?

Comment: `random()` generates a random number and `%` take the modulo of that number which will be always from 0-5, you can search `modulus operator in c` and read about it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!